# minimal introduction of promise async await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I am trying to have a quick and basic understanding of promise, async and await and how to use them. But I have not found a minimal tutorial on them. Many tutorials that I see also use something not strictly related to promise, async and await. Is there any minimal tutorial explain them really well? Thanks.

Comment: `something not strictly related to primise, async and await` async/await is "syntax sugar" for Promises - the two are inextricably linked

Comment: You could start with the [MDN for using promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), i guess. `async/await` should be moderately simple after understanding promises, as they are just syntactic sugar, that makes the use easier.

Comment: Those who voted close please explain why it should be closed.

Comment: I am asking a *minimal* tutorial, which by definition not opinionated. Please reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this example will help you.

It shows how the same thing can be done either using `then` or `async`/`await`.

```
// A new promise that will 'resolve' with the value 'Hello World!' after 1 second
const getResult = new Promise(resolveWithValue => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolveWithValue('Hello World!');
    }, 1000);
});

function printResultUsingThen() {
    getResult.then(result => {
        console.log('Then:', result);
    });
}

async function printResultUsingAwait() {
    const result = await getResult;
    console.log('Await:', result);
}

printResultUsingThen(); // prints "Then: Hello World!"
printResultUsingAwait(); // prints "Await: Hello World!"
```

EDIT: after your on-spot comments, here's a more advanced example.

I am not an expert, so my comments may not be *precisely* correct.

Feedback from an expert would be very welcome.

```
// The program begins...

// The program makes this: A function that, after 1 second,
// will 'execute' (i.e. 'call', with parentheses) its argument, resolveWithValue,
// supplying 'Hello World!' as an argument to THAT execution.
// In other words,
// it will do resolveWithValue('Hello World!'), without knowing what it means.
const executorFunction = (resolveWithValue) => {
    console.log(resolveWithValue.toString());
    // prints "function () { [native code] }" to me
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolveWithValue('Hello World!');
    }, 1000);
};

// The program makes this: A new promise that will internally generate a new function
// and pass that function's reference as an argument to executorFunction.
// When/if the interally generated function is called,
// this promise will resolve with the value that
// was passed to the interally generated function.
const getResult = new Promise(executorFunction);

// The program makes this: A function that has the capability of 'awaiting'.
// What 'async' practically means is that this function will return a promise.
const printResultUsingAwait = async () => {
    const result = await getResult;
    console.log('Await:', result);
    let weirdMessage = 'It looks like this string is returned, ';
    weirdMessage += 'but, actually, an internal promise has already been returned. ';
    weirdMessage += 'That promise now resolves with THIS message.';
    return weirdMessage;
}

// The program calls this function, storing the returned value in mysteriousVariable.
const mysteriousVariable = printResultUsingAwait();
console.log(mysteriousVariable); //  prints "Promise { pending }"

// The program learns what it has to do when/if mysteriousVariable triggers
mysteriousVariable.then(whatIsThis => {
    console.log('What is this?', whatIsThis);
    console.log(mysteriousVariable); //  prints "Promise { resolved }"
});

// The program is done, for now, and it is free to do other stuff,
// while it waits for something interesting to happen...
```

If you could `await` at the root of the program, you wouldn't let it move on to other stuff it has to do. The program itself cannot be "a promise".

(I frankly don't really know these. Maybe they're not 100% correct. This is just my understanding of the language so far.)

Comment: This is a much better and succinct example than those in many verbose tutorials. So the await/async pair basically has the same effect as Promise/then/catch?

Comment: @user1424739 Thanks. That's why I wrote it :P Yes. `async`/`await` just makes your code flatter. The equivalent of `catch` using `async`/`await` has a few... catches, though, but you can read about them in the fancy tutorials (after you've grasped the basics, IMO).

Comment: I add `console.log(resolveWithValue);` before `resolveWithValue('Hello World!');`. Then, I see `[Function]` before `Then: Hello World!`. What is that function?

Comment: Also, must `await` be used with `async`? Is there a way to just use `await` and see its effect?

Comment: @user1424739 See my updated answer.